# Limpiar localStorage al cerrar la página

Tags: javascript, angular

Estoy buscando la forma de limpiar `localStorage` solo cuando el usuario cierra la página, pero no cuando la actualiza con el fin de eliminar `localStorage` **solo cuando el usuario sale de la página** pero si la actualiza no necesito que haga nada.

Éste es el código:

```
<script>

  console.info(performance.navigation.type);
  if (performance.navigation.type == performance.navigation.TYPE_RELOAD) {
    alert("This page is reloaded")
   
  }
</script>
```

Cuando actualizo la página también se llama a este guión:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function (e) {
   var confirmationMessage = "\o/";

 (e || window.event).returnValue = confirmationMessage; //Gecko + IE
 /* if(localStorage.getItem("remember")!='True'){
 // this.globalService.destroyToken();
  localStorage.clear()
}    */     
return confirmationMessage;      
          //Webkit, Safari, Chrome
});
</script>
```

¿Existe alguna manera de diferenciar en JavaScript entre cerrar una página y actualizarla?

Todo esto lo hago con la función de poder recordar el usuario que inició sesión.

Si alguien tiene alguna idea de cómo se hace en Angular estaría agradecido.

Comment: Usa `sessionStorage`.

Comment: amigo muchisimas gracias esa era la forma en la que creo que debe hacerse voy a probar y te cuento

Comment: El problema de `sessionStorage` es que si defines `remember` en él dejará de funcionar la funcionalidad de recordar el inicio de sesión cuando el usuario vuelva a abrir la página.

Answer (score 0):

> Simple solución  window.sessionStorage  automaticamente limpia los datos luego de
> cerrar window
> Otra forma agregando un event listener.

```
window.addEventListener("beforeunload", () => localStorage.removeItem('isAuth'));
```

Comment: Tal y como ha indicado el OP en su pregunta, ese evento se dispara también cuando se recarga la página.